# VBA Excel - How to recognize certain types of data

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to build a macro that will move a table (group of cells) for me to another area of the excel spreadsheet. I've currently built this (this is the relevant part of code), but it only works with one table, as I coded it based on location of the first table. However, some of my spreadsheets have more tables, of differing locations (all the tables are stacked on top of each other, but have differing heights -- so I can't easily do what I've already done for the first table).

So my question is -- is there a way to code VBA to recognize the top left corner of each table (the data in the top left corner is always the same with each table) and then detect when the table (data) end both to the right and bottom of that top left corner, and then move all that?

I'm very new to this, and honestly am proud of my shabby "coding" below. Any help would be appreciated. I thought about using an "If..Then" statement for the detecting of the top left corner but have no idea how to go from there. Thank you for any help.

```
' Moving data and headers
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("E6:E14").Cut Worksheets("Inventory").Range("A1:A9")
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("F6:F14").Cut Worksheets("Inventory").Range("B1:B9")
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("G6:G14").Cut Worksheets("Inventory").Range("C1:C9")
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("H8:H14").Cut Worksheets("Inventory").Range("D3:D9")
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("I8:I14").Cut Worksheets("Inventory").Range("E3:E9")
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("J8:J14").Cut Worksheets("Inventory").Range("F3:F9")
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("K8:K14").Cut Worksheets("Inventory").Range("G3:G9")
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L8:L14").Cut Worksheets("Inventory").Range("H3:H9")
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("M8:M14").Cut Worksheets("Inventory").Range("I3:I9")
' Merging and putting in Days Worked
Range("D1:I1").Select
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
Selection.Merge
```

**Sample Table:**

[image: sample]

Comment: Could you please define "table".  Are you speaking of the object "table" that can be inserted into a worksheet? Or the worksheet itself?  edit: I think you mean object, with them being stacked...

Comment: There is a way to recognize the top-left corner of each table **IF** the tables are `ListObjects` (created from the Insert | Table ribbon).  Simply iterate each `ListObject` on the worksheet, and copy its `DataBodyRange`. If they are simple formatted cells, then you would have to use some other logic, which will be more complicated.

Comment: Have you considered setting them as visible or not?

Comment: @peege Sorry I wasn't clearer. It's not actually a table object, but simply a grouping of cells that I was referring to as a "table."

Comment: OK, that changes everything.  What exactly are you trying to do then?  Specifically?  If this happens, move this data to HERE..  Etc.

Comment: @peege Well as you can see, I currently have the program cutting a table from one location and pasting it to another location. However, some spreadsheets I'm working with will have more than one table, and of varying sizes possibly (varying only in one row added, or such). So, I need the program to be able to detect when there are multiple tables, and move them right under the original table that was moved. If it helps, each table has the same header, so I was thinking it could be possible to have the table look for the same header each time, and then implement Gary's CornerFinder below maybe.

Comment: It would help a lot if you can show us how your tables are organized, what are dynamically changing and what is constant. Are there headers or markers or any reference?

Comment: @L42 Here's a picture of a table: http://imgur.com/cAzsUlZ  The dynamic parts that could change are simply: 1) more data filling up those blank spaces 2) an extra row or two added to the bottom of the table or 3) the report each group of hours is credited in. So, to be clear, the yellow part, the header of the table, is static and stays the same with every table.

Comment: @L42 Thanks for editing my question with that table. I didn't know you could do that.

Comment: Ah, you can only do that if you've earned enough reputation. Btw, this is possible. I'll see what I can do. While I'm at it, check this [StackOverflow Question Checklist](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) to help you improve your questions in the future and attract more people to answer it.

Comment: @L42 Okay! Thanks so much for all of your help. I'm pretty new to this, so I've been working with a rudimentary knowledge, and getting most of my commands from viewing the source of a macro after I do the action that I want it to do automatically for me. And thanks for the link, I'll definitely use it in any future questions I may have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok based on your sample data and sample code, try this out.

```
Sub Test()
    Const tlh As String = "Credited in Report"
    With Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change to suit
        Dim tl As Range, bl As Range
        Dim first_add As String, tbl_loc As Variant
        Set tl = .Cells.Find(tlh)
        If Not tl Is Nothing Then
            first_add = tl.Address
        Else
            MsgBox "Table does not exist.": Exit Sub
        End If
        Do
            If Not IsArray(tbl_loc) Then
                tbl_loc = Array(tl.Address)
            Else
                ReDim Preserve tbl_loc(UBound(tbl_loc) + 1)
                tbl_loc(UBound(tbl_loc)) = tl.Address
            End If
            Set tl = .Cells.FindNext(tl)
        Loop While tl.Address <> first_add
        Dim i As Long, lrow As Long, tb_cnt As Long: tb_cnt = 0
        For i = LBound(tbl_loc) To UBound(tbl_loc)
            Set bl = .Cells.Find(vbNullString, .Range(tbl_loc(i)) _
                , , , xlByColumns, xlNext)
            lrow = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & _
                   Sheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            .Range(.Range(tbl_loc(i)).Offset(IIf(tb_cnt <> 0, 1, 0), 0), _
                bl.Offset(-1, 0)).Resize(, 9).Copy _
                Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & lrow).Offset(IIf(lrow = 1, 0, 1), 0)
            tb_cnt = tb_cnt + 1
            Set bl = Nothing
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

This consolidates the data in one table.
I used copy instead of cut to be safe. You can change it whatever suits you.
I also use another sheet for the output since I'm using copy.

For example you have below in Sheet1:

[image]

It will be consolidated in Sheet2 like this:

[image]

Is this what you're trying? If not, you can go ahead and learn from the code.
Then once you do, adjust it to suit your needs. :-) HTH.

Comment: Thanks so much for your code! It worked almost perfectly, I had to change just a little bit of it to account for adding a new sheet. I'm very thankful for your help :)  I do have one final question if that's okay haha. Looking through it, I believe you check the box right below "credit in report" and keep copying until the box below is blank. However, I have some tables that look like this: http://imgur.com/5dP6PQi  -- would it be possible to make it check Credited in report, but then instead always check under the first column of dates? That column is consistent throughout the sheets I'll...

Comment: ...be working with, column H -- but of course the row it is in can change. If that's not possible based on how you coded it, that's okay -- I'm so very happy with what you've already given me and I can possibly just eliminate those data points or make them have their own row, since they're not present in every sheet and table I'll be going through.

Comment: @hymatty Of course that is possible. We looked for the cell that contains **Credited in Report** and used it as reference in finding the last cell with data. You only need to use *Offset property* to get to the correct column. So change this part `.Range(tb_loc(i))` to `.Range(tb_loc(i)).Offset(0, 3)` since you want to check 3 cells from it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a **rectangular** range, then to find its upper left-hand corner and lower right-hand corner:

```
Sub CornerFinder(RR As Range)
    Dim addy1 As String, addy2 As String
    addy1 = RR(1).Address(0, 0)

    Dim nLastRow As Long, nLastColumn As Long
    nLastRow = RR.Rows.Count + RR.Row - 1
    nLastColumn = RR.Columns.Count + RR.Column - 1
    addy2 = Cells(nLastRow, nLastColumn).Address(0, 0)

    MsgBox addy1 & vbCrLf & addy2
End Sub
```

Tested with:

```
Sub MAIN()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("B9:J37")
    Call CornerFinder(r)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have a follow up question for you though, as I am quite new. How would I implement this in my program? Would I use your CornerFinder to store the corners of the table as Strings, and then another program would use said strings as the locations for what to move? I'm not sure how something like that would look, but I'm excited to implement your solution if possible into something like that.